# How to resolve and create Generic Classes in AngularJS Injector

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

have a class like below,

```
export class SiteEventServiceType<T> {
}
```

How do i need to create the instance for the above class using angularjs 2 Injector.

Tried But Not working:

```
 Injector.resolveAndCreate([SiteEventServiceType<string>]).get(SiteEventServiceType<string>);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example was posted quite a while back at https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/1779

```
@Component(
  selector: 'my-component',
  // now providers:
  injectables: const [
      const Binding(
          const TypeLiteral<Stream<String>>, 
          toFactory: MyComponent.streamFactory)
  ]
)
@View(
  directives: const [MyChildComponent],
  template: '<my-child-component></my-child-component>'
)
class MyComponent {
  static Stream<String> streamFactory() => new Stream.fromIterable(['Hello']);
}

@Component(
  selector: 'my-child-component'
)
@View(
  template: '{{lastValue}}'
)
class MyChildComponent {
  String lastValue;

  MyChildComponent(Stream<String> stringStream) {
    stringStream.listen((value) => lastValue = value);
  }
}
```

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1691 c
- and the still open issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5704